# XML + XSD => Java?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2

I need to make the above equation comes true!

I have an XML file with its XSD schema, and I need to get the Java classes with the required code to parse the XML file and construct java objects..

I am asking here about a standard (or defacto like apache) utility to make the above request comes ture....

Is JAXB can make this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [JAX-B](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html), the Java XML-to-object binding API.

Comment: Does JAX-B do the required XML parsing staff to populate the objects?

Comment: Yes, it does.  This is your cue to read some of the docs instead of being spoon-fed here.  Start with this: https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/section_1_3-Hello-World.html#Hello World

Comment: +1 Also since JAXB is a standard there are multiple implementations check out EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php and my blog: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com for even more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need a library to compile the xsd into Java types. JAXB and [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) are two such libraries.

With XMLBeans you can run a simple command to generate the Java types:

```
scomp -out types.jar myschema.xsd
```

Comment: The JAXB command line is also simple: xjc -d out myschema.xsd